# How can I determine which deployment I am in at runtime in an Azure-hosted Node cloud service?

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a NodeJS Azure cloud service. I would like to make another instance for testing which would connect to a different database than the production site. I also want to avoid maintaining two separate configurations just to accomplish this. Is there any way I can get enough information about which deployment is currently running into my Node app in order to change the database connection based on that?

Just looking at the Azure management portal, it looks like I could use the `Deployment Name`, `Deployment Label`, `Public Virtual IP Address`, or `Deployment ID`. There may be other methods I have missed. The problem is I'm not sure how to get any of these for the current app into Node.

Comment: You'll have to use Management API for that. The role environment will provide you with the deployment id and you can hardcode the subscription id (better make it a setting which you'll not change in the next five years) and you enumerate all the services in the subscription until you find your current deployment in there.

Comment: @sharptooth Could you elaborate on this? "The role environment will provide you with the deployment id..." I think I've found the API call that will get me a list of my deployed services, but I'm not sure how to get the current deployment ID. Also, if I can get the deployment ID, could I not base the decision on that?

Comment: This is where I would recommend you start: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/subscriptionManagement. This is the implementation of Management API @sharptooth mentioned.

Comment: @raddevon: There's `RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId` property in the runtime for that.

Comment: `Also, if I can get the deployment ID, could I not base the decision on that?` - No. Deployment ID is just a GUID. Do take a look here: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/03/16/programmatically-finding-deployment-slot-from-code-running-in-windows-azure/. Though the code is in C#, it should give you some idea. HTH.